# Django behind Nginx build_absolute_uri returns http://host/

Tags: django, nginx

Django's `request.build_absolute_uri()` function returns `http://host/` for my URL pointing to `/` on localhost and any domain I host it on.

Django is behind Nginx and both are docker containers. Here's a docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
    env_file: ./.env
    volumes:
      - ./src:/django_project
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/tmp/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - django
    links:
      - django
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
```

Django is behind Nginx and the Nginx config is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 80M;
    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://django:8000/;
        proxy_read_timeout  240s;
        uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on;

        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking it's definitely Nginx that's the bad guy, but what am I missing?